# Ho do I enumerate duplicated values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following dataframe:

```
  col
0   A
1   B
2   A
3   A
4   A
5   A
6   A
7   B
8   B
9   A
```

I want to enumerate duplicated values of the column `col` in an efficient way starting with 1 so the dataset should be like this:

```
  col  counts
0   A       1
1   B       1
2   A       2
3   A       3
4   A       4
5   A       5
6   A       6
7   B       2
8   B       3
9   A       7
```

I tried this code that works fine but too slow.

```py
counter = defaultdict(int)
counts = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    counter[row['col']] += 1
    counts.append(counter[row['col']])

df['counts'] = counts
```

Is there a better and faster way to do the same?

Comment: Use cumcount().